# Unable to complete oauth web workflow for GitHub in golang

Tags: http, github, oauth, go

I'm trying to implement oauth-workflow for GitHub in golang and using https://github.com/franela/goreq to perform http(s) requests.

There is a section in which GitHub returns a `code` and you have to make a `POST` request to https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token with `code`, `client_id` and `client_secret`.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/franela/goreq"

type param struct {
  code string
  client_id string
  client_secret string
}

func main() {
  params := param {code: "XX", client_id:"XX", client_secret: "XX"}
  req := goreq.Request{
    Method : "POST",
    Uri : "https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token",
    Body : params,
  }
  req.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  req.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
  res, _ := req.Do()
  fmt.Println(res.Body.ToString())
}
```

It is giving `404` with `{"error":"Not Found"}` message always.
While using Python, I'm getting the correct results with the same input data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are generating empty JSON objects. Your struct fields should start in capitals for the JSON encoder to be able to encode them.

```
type goodparam struct {
    Code         string `json:"code"`
    ClientId     string `json:"client_id"`
    ClientSecret string `json:"client_secret"`
}
```

See [this in action](http://play.golang.org/p/MwTj2zsrlS).

Answer (score 0):

You should double check your 'client_secret' and 'client_id' (must be right because you get the code) if it is correct, apparently Github returns HTTP status code 404 if it is wrong.